# Difference in consecutive rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which has any integer number. There is no specific criteria for a number to start but next row will be +2000 in number then above row and so on. So I want to find out through query where the difference of 2 rows are not 2000. Could you please help me on this? Comparison would be as follows:

```
Row 1 = 1000
2 =     3000
3       4000
4=      6000
5=       7000
```

Then only 3 and 5 should be output as the difference of Row 3 and Row 5 is not 2000. Row 3 should be compared with 2 and 5 should be compared with 4.

My data looks like :

Label                         Formorder                   date

test                          480000                           3/31/2015
test2                         481000                           3/31/2014
test3                          482000                           3/31/2015
test4                          483000                           3/31/2014

[image]

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or above, you can use the `LAG` function.

`LAG` will give you a value in the previous row, compare this value to see if it is 2000 lower than the current row:

```
WITH diffs as (
    SELECT rowValue,
           rowValue - LAG(rowValue) OVER (ORDER BY rowValue) diff
    FROM   dataTable)
SELECT rowValue
FROM   diffs
WHERE  diff <> 2000
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59d28/2

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN-based approach should work on SQL Server 2008.

In the query below, row numbers are added to the source data. Then, an inner join connects the current row to the previous row *if and only if* the previous row's value is not exactly 2000 less than the current row.

```
WITH Data AS (
  SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowValue)
  FROM   dataTable
)

SELECT n.rowValue
FROM data n
  JOIN data p ON p.RowNumber = n.RowNumber - 1
    AND p.rowValue != n.rowValue - 2000
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59d28/10

Comment: Could you please help me with this query?                                                                     
                                                                                                                                select distinct  v.label, v.rownumber, v.Date, v1.rownumber, v1.Date
from datatable t
join datavalue v on t.table = v.table 
join datavalue  v1 on v1.rownumber = v.rownumber
where v1.rownumber <>  v.rownumber+1000

Comment: Try changing the last part of your query to something like: `join datavalue v1 on v1.rownumber = v.rownumber - 1 where v1.value <> v.value+1000`. That is, join v1 to v on **both** v1.rownumber = v.rownumber - 1 _and_ v1.value <> v.value + 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
declare @t table(id int, v int)

insert into @t values
(1, 1000),
(2, 3000),
(4, 7000),
(6, 9000),
(11, 11000),
(17, 17000)


select * from @t t1
outer apply(select * from (
                select top 1 id as previd, v as prevv 
                from @t t2 
                where t2.id < t1.id 
                order by id desc)t 
            where t1.v - t.prevv <> 2000) oa
where oa.prevv is not null
```

Output:

```
id  v       previd  prevv
4   7000    2      3000
17  17000   11     11000
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID (row) does not skip

```
select t2.*  
 from table t1 
 jion table t2 
   on t2.ID = t1.ID + 1 
  and t2.value <> t1.value + 2000
```